# Auth0 user info method returns user object with only sub property

Tags: angular, authentication, auth0

I am building authentication for my angular app and I am trying to get userinfo from the auth0 when someone login. I am using the auth0 docs as guidance and i get the 'user' object but it has only sub property no name, email etc.

```
Object {sub: "auth0|5**********7"}
```

I tried with facebook, linkedin, google logins and signed up without social media but result was the same just 'auth0 |' part changes. This is my auth.service.ts :

```
auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
  clientID: 'myClientID',
  domain: 'myDomain.auth0.com',
  responseType: 'token id_token',
  audience: 'https://myDomain.auth0.com/userinfo',
  redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  scope: 'openid'
})

handleAuthentication(): void {
  this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
    if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
      window.location.hash = '';
      this.setSession(authResult);
      this.router.navigate(['/dersler']);

      // This is for getting user info after authentication (taken from the auth0 docs but revised)
      this.auth0.client.userInfo(authResult.accessToken, function(err, user) {
      // This method will make a request to the /userinfo endpoint 
      // and return the user object, which contains the user's information, 
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(user);
        return;
      });
      // method to get user info ends here

    } else if (err) {
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
}
```

I tried getting userinfo with http method in the auth0 docs but it returns same user object only with 'sub' property. Why it doesn't return other user info?

EDIT (SOLVED):
I changed the 'scope' property of auth0 from 'openid' to 'openid profile' and now it returns user object with name and all other info successfully.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is in your `scope` parameter, you can change it to `scope: 'openid profile email phone'`. Then log out, log in and you're done.

More info [here](https://community.auth0.com/questions/4766/auth0-getuserinfo-does-not-return-all-user-data)

Comment: you saved us! it took two of us 2 days and i just saw this and figured it out. you are a hero, thank you!